# Find limit of $x^2/e^x$ as x approaches infinity

Tags: limits

limit of $x^2/e^x$ as $x$ approaches infinity

I can't solve it even with l hopital rule
any help?

Comment: Try applying L'Hopital multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The beauty of L'Hopital's rule is that it can applied multiple times until your indeterminate form goes away.

For instance, you have

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{e^x}$$

which is an indeterminate form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. If you apply the rule once you have:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2x}{e^x}$$

However, this is again an indeterminate form of $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$. So you can apply L'Hopital once again until you don't have an indeterminate form.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2}{e^x}$$

Now, this limit is not indeterminate and it can easily be seen via intuition or graph that the limit should be zero.

[image: Graph of 2/e^x]

Therefore,

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x^2}{e^x} = 0$$

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 4):

Consider $r>0$; then
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^r}{e^x}=0
$$
Indeed, you can start from $x<e^x$ (for $x>0$), so $\frac{x}{2}<e^{x/2}$ and therefore
$$
0<\frac{x}{e^x}<\frac{2}{e^{x/2}}
$$
and the squeeze theorem allows to conclude. Of course also l’Hôpital works:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^x}
$$
For the general limit, write it as
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{e^{x/r}}\right)^{\!r}=
\lim_{x\to\infty}r^r\left(\frac{x/r}{e^{x/r}}\right)^{\!r}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Just apply De L'Hôpital rule twice:

first time:

$$\frac{2x}{e^x}$$

Second time:

$$\frac{2}{e^x} ~~ \to ~~ 0 ~~~ \text{as} ~~~ x \to +\infty$$

Answer (score 1):

This limit is actually trivial since you should know that $x^2$ grows slower than $e^x$. But here the long version using L'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} {x^2\over e^x} = \lim_{x\to \infty} {2\over e^x} =    2 \cdot \lim_{x\to \infty} {1\over e^x} = 2\cdot 0 = 0$$

Comment: In which Universe $0\cdot 2 = 2$??

Comment: @KimPeek that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

Apply L'Hôpital  two times:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{x^2}{e^x}\overset{\text{L'Hô}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{2x}{e^x}\overset{\text{L'Hô}}=\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\frac{2}{e^x}=\boxed {\color{red}0}$$

Comment: There is typo! it's $2$ not $0$, in the penultimate term

Comment: answer given to me was indeed zero, is 0/infinite = 0?

Comment: @user343213 nope, there was a typo!