# Resolution of a limit

Tags: analysis

I want to formally prove that this limit is equal to $0$

$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2}{x^{3}} e^{-\frac{1}{x^{2}}}$

can anybody help me?

Comment: Similar: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665679/find-limit-of-x2-ex-as-x-approaches-infinity

Comment: Using $u=1/x$ the limit becomes$$\lim_{|u|\to\infty}\frac{2u^3}{e^{u^2}}=0$$because any polynomial is $o(e^u)=o(e^{u^2}) $.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to

$$\lim_{t\to\infty}t^{3/2}e^{-t}=0$$ as it is well-known that the exponential increases faster than any polynomial.